# AssertionError: Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissions on a view that does not have `.model` or `.queryset` property

Tags: django, permissions, django-rest-framework

I previously had this view on my project:

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated


from rest_api.my_app.serializer import MySerializer
from my_project.models import Bag


class MyView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (JSONParser,)
    queryset = Bag.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)


    @staticmethod
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = MySerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(),
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

However I later realized that I did not need the queryset and so I deleted that line and the
permission and queryset to remain with:

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser


from rest_api.my_app.serializer import MySerializer


class MyView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (JSONParser,)
    @staticmethod
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = MySerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(),
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

If I try to run the code i get this error message:

```
AssertionError: Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissions on a view that does not have     `.model` or `.queryset` property.'
```

Comment: Your queryset should be `queryset = Bag.objects.all()`

Comment: I think you have a typo: a `,` after `serializer.save()`

Comment: @Sohan it's ok because there is another statement under the if

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissions on a view that does not have \`.queryset\` property or overrides the \`.get\_queryset()\` method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335736/cannot-apply-djangomodelpermissions-on-a-view-that-does-not-have-queryset-pro)

Answer (score 10):

This is because you removed the permission_classes.
You can use
`permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)`