# Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissions on a view that does not have `.queryset` property or overrides the `.get_queryset()` method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am getting the error ".accepted_renderer not set on Response resp api django".

I am following the django rest-api tutorial. 
Django version i am using 1.8.3
I followed the tutorial till first part. It worked properly. But when i continued the 2nd part in sending response, i got an error

```
Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissions on a view that does not have `.queryset` property or overrides the `.get_queryset()` method.
```

Then i tried other ways i got

```
.accepted_renderer not set on Response resp api django
```

Please help me out. I think its permission issue.

Comment: Could you post your code for clarification?

Comment: @EdwinLunando I also got same result. it is very easy to reproduce, just follow tutorial http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/ from official site

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You probably have set `DjangoModelPermissions` as a default permission class in your settings. Something like:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissions',
    )
}
```

`DjangoModelPermissions` can only be applied to views that have a `.queryset` property or `.get_queryset()` method.

Since Tutorial 2 uses FBVs, you probably need to convert it to a CBV or an easy way is to specify a different permission class for that view.
You must be using the `api_view` decorator in your view. You can then define `permissions` like below:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework import permissions

@api_view([..])
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
def my_view(request)
    ...
```

To resolve the renderer error, you need to add the corresponding renderer to your settings.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.<corresponding_renderer>',
        ...
    )
}
```

Comment: Quick fix, comment out the `'rest_framework.renders.DjangoModelPermissions'` line for now -- if you are following the DRF Tutorial 2; and perhaps you had added that in `settings.py` during the _homepage_ example.

Comment: In your second code block, you will need to `import rest_framework.permissions` as well.

Comment: This is a much better answer as it allows the dev to decide on a particular permission class to use with the view. Appreciate it as this led me to the why's. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

I got it working in another way.
My logged in user was the superuser which i have created.
So i have created another user from admin and made him staff user and provided all the permissions. Then logged in to admin by that user.

In settings.py file i changed code.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ]
}
```

And it worked.

Comment: Great! Actually, the issue was in the permissions. Defining permissions explicitly in the settings or via the decorator in FBV would solve the issue.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, (for tutorial 2, `djangorestframework` ver 3.7.7), it works when I change settings to:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Solution for me was as pointed out by @ProfNandaa above

> Quick fix, comment out the
>   'rest_framework.renders.DjangoModelPermissions' line for now -- if you
>   are following the DRF Tutorial 2; and perhaps you had added that in
>   settings.py during the homepage example.

I had indeed added this from the homepage example before embarking on the tutorial and hit the same issue.

When I commented out the offending code

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissions',
    )
}
```

from settings.py it all worked fine again.

Answer (score 6):

There are lots of good solutions already listed here. I also faced the same problem in second tutorial. It was showing:

> Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly on a view that does
>   not set `.queryset` or have a `.get_queryset()` method.

I changed the `settings.py` to exclude `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES` like below:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
    ]
}
```

Then it runs successfully. I tried this before I have found these answers.

Answer (score 2):

From [Django Rest Framework's documentation,](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangomodelpermissions) you can add this to your view:

`queryset = User.objects.none()`

Answer (score 1):

For test, you can use

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ]
}
```

This setting defaults to allowing unrestricted access.
[Documentions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/)

Answer (score 0):

if you're using @app_view then you have to simply remove this part:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly',
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissions',
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
        
    ],
    
}
```